# Deploying Spark and Hadoop on different cluster/machines

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Can Spark and Hadoop/Yarn be deployed on different cluster ?

The problem scenario is as follows:

1. The data/hive tables already resides in Hadoop lake.
2. I want to implement some BI processing on this data.
3. One way is deploy Spark on this Hadoop cluster and utilize the existing CPU/RAM resources for data processing. This works fine.
4. However I want to have different set to Spark Cluster(4 worker nodes) which fetches data from Hadoop lake (data size not more than 500GB), do the processing and display output from Spark cluster. Ocassionally, the processed data will be stored back in Hadoop lake. The reason for this is it gives me more control over my BI logic and doesn't interferes with existing Hadoop lake. I am 'OK' with network traffic. Is this approach possible?

Please suggest

Regards
Upendra

Comment: what are the reasons for deploying spark on separate cluster?

Comment: This is to have separate and controlled Spark cluster. Its more from functional perspective to have different clusters. Is this possible ?

Comment: I don't see a problem here, have you installed Spark on your second cluster and tried it yet?

Comment: No.. can you provide any doc/sample code implementing this approach ?

Comment: Try a spark.textFile("hdfs://remoteNamenode:port/directory")

Comment: I tried connecting Hadoop lake from a Spark Cluster. The above command executes. But when I issue .collect() command, the spark cluster tries to find data in local spark cluster.(i.e it doesnt fetches from Hadoop cluster)